# Lock Tables for Select and Update

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have 2 MySQL tables:

pages:

```
id INT,
name VARCHAR,
view_count INT
```

page_views:

```
page_id INT
viewed_at DATETIME,
ip VARCHAR(15),
processed INT(1)
```

When someone views a page, a new record is added to `page_views` table with `processed = 0` flag. 
Every N minutes unprocessed records should be extracted, counted and added to `view_count` property of `pages` table.

Without transactions and locking it would look like:

```
SELECT page_id, COUNT(ip) AS cnt FROM page_views WHERE processed = 0 GROUP BY page_id;
UPDATE page_views SET processed = 1 WHERE processed = 0;
UPDATE pages SET view_count = view_count + ...
```

But in this case new records can be added to `page_views` between the first 2 queries. So we should lock `page_views` table for writing.
But there's another one case is possible, when 3rd query fails for some reason, but `processed` flag was already updated on `page_views` table and these records won't be considered next time.
It means we also should use transactions for that.

So the algorithm should be the following:

```
-- lock `page_views` for writing
-- start transaction
SELECT page_id, COUNT(ip) AS cnt FROM page_views WHERE processed = 0 GROUP BY page_id;
UPDATE page_views SET processed = 1 WHERE processed = 0;
-- unlock `page_views`
UPDATE pages SET view_count = view_count + ...
-- commit transaction
```

But according to [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html),  `LOCK TABLES` is not transaction-safe so I'm looking for the proper way of handling this case.

---

Answering comments:

Example of why using only transactions doesn't work in this case:

```
mysql_1> SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
mysql_1> START TRANSACTION;
mysql_1> SELECT * FROM page_views;
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| page_id | date       | ip        | processed |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|    2832 | 2015-09-10 | 127.0.0.1 |         1 |
|    2832 | 2015-09-11 | 127.0.0.1 |         1 |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
mysql_2> INSERT INTO page_views SET page_id = 2832, date='2015-09-12', ip='127.0.0.1', processed=0;
mysql_1> UPDATE page_views SET processed = 1 WHERE processed = 0;
mysql_1> COMMIT;
mysql_1> SELECT * FROM page_views;
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| page_id | date       | ip        | processed |
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|    2832 | 2015-09-10 | 127.0.0.1 |         1 |
|    2832 | 2015-09-11 | 127.0.0.1 |         1 |
|    2832 | 2015-09-12 | 127.0.0.1 |         1 | <-- this should be 0
+---------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: why do you need the lock table? as soon as you use a transaction, you should be safe here anyways?

Comment: Using transaction guarantees that second query (UPDATE page_views SET processed = 1 WHERE processed = 0) will update only records which were selected with the first query even if new records were added between the two calls?

Comment: Check out the documentation regarding isolation levels & use of SELECT FOR UPDATE - but as @Olli says no need for locking, transactions will be ok.

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE doesn't work in this case since I need to prevent inserting new rows rather than updating existing ones. 
REPEATABLE READ also doesn't work since if I run UPDATE query inside a transaction, it will affect rows which were added outside the transaction by another process.